# Categorizing array items using collections?

Tags: arrays, vba, collections

I am trying to categorize items in a couple of arrays based on a list of possible categories. For now, I have managed to associate a category with each item in the two arrays, but now I would like to re-group them such that they are in groups with other items within their category.

I am stuck because I have created a list of unique items that I want to use as the new collection names. In my mind, this would require a For-Loop but I know that creating variables in a loop is always frowned upon. Also, it's not working. Here's the code as it is now:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(ItemList1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(MasterList, 2)
        check = ItemList1(i) Like MasterList(3, j)
        If check Then
            ItemList1Categories(i) = MasterList(8, j)
        End If
    Next
Next  'Creates first array of categories


For i = 1 To UBound(ItemList2)
    For j = 1 To UBound(MasterList, 2)
        check4 = ItemList2(i) Like MasterList(3, j)
        If check4 Then
            ItemList2Categories(i) = MasterList(8, j)
        End If
    Next
Next 'Creates second array of categories

On Error Resume Next
  For Each a In ItemList1Categories
     Categories.Add a, a
  Next 'Stores unique items from first array of categories to collection

On Error Resume Next
  For Each a In ItemList2Categories
     Categories.Add a, a
  Next 'Adds unique items from second array of categories to collection



'This part is bad and I would appreciate some help
For i = 1 To Categories.Count
    Set Categories(i) = New Collection
Next
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem with the bad part?

Comment: It doesn't name the new collection according to the item in the reference collection (categories)